# Convert Osmdroid latitude/longitude to JXMapKit

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am developing a software, some kind of GPS. It has two sides. Admin(PC) and Clients(Android).

Android version use `Osmdroid` maps, and what I want to do is grab the Mappoint that I created in Android, insert it to the database and than read it from other devices.

The problem is that if the actual Latitude and Longitude of point that I create is for example 42.222222 and 23.55555, after doing this:

```
IProjection project = view.getProjection();
final GeoPoint geo = (GeoPoint)project.fromPixels((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY());
```

*e is a motion event

the actual value that is stored in latitude and longitude of that `GeoPoint` is 42222222 or 2355555. The coma just disappears from that values, so it is useless to usage in PC version. I don't know how the `OSMdroid` is working with this values, but is there any way to convert it to its standard format like -42.584254 ?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just found a solution ,it must be just divided by 1E6 :)